# Weblogic process killed in redhat 6.5

Tags: java, weblogic, redhat

I have two weblogic domains each one has one managed server, the problem is that every 3 or 4 hours may be less than the four process are killed suddenly and in domain console i found that.

> ./startWebLogic.sh: line 175: 53875 Killed                  ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.policy ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}

There is no problem in free memory in server.

[free memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf0p1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible explanations for this message are the Linux OOM killer and the WebLogic node manager.

You should be able to find evidence for the first in /var/log/messages (grep -i -n 'killed process' /var/log/messages). If so, add up all the Xmx parameters of the running java processes, add 35% and see if that total tops the total amount of memory in the machine. If it does, tweak the Xmx parameters downwards.

The easier way to test for the second is to kill the nodemanager process, keep it down and see if the problem persists (kill -9 `ps -ef | grep odeManager | awk '{print $2}'`). If the problem does not reoccur, check the WebLogic admin console on how the "Panic action" and "Failure action" are configured for each server and set them to "No Action". In that case also check the nodemanager and server logs to figure out why the node manager killed your managed server processes.